# How to create a completly custom theme in Tuleap?

Tags: themes, tuleap

i've been following this part of the Tuleap doc: 
https://tuleap.net/wiki/index.php?pagename=Customization%2FThemes&group_id=101
 (which last from 2013...) with little to no success. and i can't find any doc concerning creating a custom theme more recent. nor any other information.

is anyone trying to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is now out-dated.

If you want to brand Tuleap to your company, you need to have the Tuleap sources and manage it as a copy of the official theme (and keep it updated each time you upgrade).

Note: there is a massive rework on all UI part underway and it will change 100% of how things are rendered. First bits will land in november and the move should completed in Spring 2017.